# Not able to iterate over interface. Looping variable resulting in undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, for-loop, ionic4

In my example, I have created an interface called product and pushing data into it. For that, I have created a total function that combines data coming from two sources and pushing into the interface object. But while I iterate over it, the looping variable is becoming undefined.
In total() function when I iterate over the cart variable, the value of p is undefined. Any idea why?

Thank you in advance
.ts

```
  import { stocks } from '../../class-objects/stocks'


    export interface Product {

      product_id : number;
      name : string;
      image_url : string;
      margin : number;
      gst : number;
      description : string;
      date : Date;
      sub_id : number;
      unit : string;
      quantity : number;
      stocks : stocks [] 

    }

    export class ItemsPage implements OnInit {

      myListObject = [] as Array<Product>

      @ViewChild('cart', {static: false, read: ElementRef})fab: ElementRef;

      constructor(private cartService: CartService, private modalCtrl: ModalController, public productService : ProductService) { }


      ngOnInit() {

        this.cartService.getProductDetails().subscribe(data =>{
          this.products = data;
          this.filter_products = this.products;

          console.log(this.products)
        })
        this.cart = this.cartService.getCart();
        this.cartItemCount = this.cartService.getCartItemCount();
      }

      onChange(quantity,product) { // quantity coming from select from html

        this.selected_quant  = quantity;
      }

      addToCart(product) {

        this.total(product,this.selected_quant)

      }


      total(product,quantity) {

        console.log(this.cart)

        for(let p of this.cart ) {
          console.log("Value of p="+p) // resulting in undefined

          console.log(p.image_url)  // resulting in undefined
          console.log(p.name) // resulting in undefined
          console.log(product.product_id)

          if(p.product_id === product.product_id){
            p.quantity = product.quantity
        }
        else {

          this.myListObject.push(product,quantity)
            console.log(this.myListObject)
          this.cartService.addProduct(this.myListObject);
          this.animateCSS('tada');
        }
      }

        }
      }
```

cartservice.ts

```
  private cart = [];
  private cartItemCount = new BehaviorSubject(0);


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProductDetails (): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('http://[::1]:3000/products?&filter[include][][relation]=stocks')

  }

     getCart() {
        return this.cart;
      }

      getCartItemCount() {
        return this.cartItemCount;
      }

      addProduct(product) {
        let added = false;
        for (let p of this.cart) {
          console.log("cartservice " +p) // resulting in undefined 
          if (p.product_id === product.product_id) {
            p.quantity = product.quantity;

            added = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!added) {
          this.cart.push(product);
        }
        this.cartItemCount.next(this.cartItemCount.value + 1);
      }
```

Comment: show us your html code where you do the iteration

Comment: iteration in typescript. In total function  for(let p of this.cart), the value of p is undefined

Comment: ah ok you need to put all your service!

Comment: I have uploaded the service. Even in service in addproduct() function, the looping variable is undefined

Comment: the total method is called in addToCart() but addToCart is never called in the code that you have posted.

Comment: It is called on button click html. Sorry

Comment: Update code for cartservice.ts, `class CartService` is missing. There is a constructor, but it's not inside class.

Comment: Sorry. But cartservice contains only that much data

Answer (score 0):

Replace `total` function.

```
total(product, quantity) {
  console.log(this.cartService.getCart());

  for (let p of this.cartService.getCart()) {
    console.log("Value of p=" + p); // resulting in undefined

    console.log(p.image_url); // resulting in undefined
    console.log(p.name); // resulting in undefined
    console.log(product.product_id);

    if (p.product_id === product.product_id) {
      p.quantity = product.quantity;
    } else {
      this.myListObject.push(product, quantity);
      console.log(this.myListObject);
      this.cartService.addProduct(this.myListObject);
      this.animateCSS("tada");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Of course I have class and constructor in service. The problem lies in total() function in item page on this line - for(let p of this.cart ) { console.log("Value of p="+p) // resulting in undefined The value of p is returning undefined . This is problem I stated

Comment: Then next time, provide all the code, not just a portion that will confuse people.
Check my edit. @pratikjaiswal